# Re-ordering columns in pandas dataframe based on column header names, where the name of the columns are string, contains the numeric number at the end

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sorting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pFqr.png)
Before sorting:

If we look at the file, the columns are unsorted.  Example column headers are L0_S0_F0, L0_S0_F4, L0_S0_F2, L0_S0_F10, L0_S0_F6, L0_S0_F8 and L0_S0_F12 respectively

File after merging

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7j6f.png):
After sorting properly, We need to have data frame with sequentially ordered columns with their order L0_S0_F0, L0_S0_F2, L0_S0_F4, L0_S0_F6, L0_S0_F8, L0_S0_F10 and L0_S0_F12 respectively

Here the column name, example L0_S0_F0, which represents Line 0, station 0 and feature 2. Now we need to sort the columns based on the name of the features( digit after 'F').

File after reordering

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7j6f.png)

Comment: `df = df.reindex(sorted(df.columns, key=lambda x: int(x.split(_)[-1][1:]), axis=1)` ???

Comment: Don't post images. Post your data frame as text

Comment: unfortunately did not work

Comment: Can you explain how it didn't work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be :

```
df = df.reindex(sorted(df.columns[1:], key=lambda x: int(x.split('_')[-1][1:])), axis=1)
```

Comment: unfortunately did not work...May be we need to adjust the 'key', as the column header is string, ending with number... Example L0_S0_F20

Comment: @veereshkanaboor: feel free to modify the code. Yeah key part you may required to change. I don't know how it didn't work
 It worked for me,for your sample data frame. I was extracting numbers from the columns and based on that trying to do sort.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.... actually, very minute modification has worked for me. Once again thank you verymuch.  df=num_cat_merged_raw_25.drop(['Id','Response'],axis='columns')
df = df.reindex(sorted(df.columns[0:], key=lambda x: int(x.split('_')[-1][1:])), axis=1)

Answer (score 0):

df=num_cat_merged_raw_25.drop(['Id','Response'],axis='columns') df = df.reindex(sorted(df.columns[0:], key=lambda x: int(x.split('_')[-1][1:])), axis=1)

This code worked for me. Thank you Pygirl, for driving me towards the logic :)